# Как создать свой браузер с возможностью скачивания видео с любого сайта?

Tags: java, android, webbrowser

Как создать свой браузер с возможностью скачивания видео с любого сайта для android? Во многих браузерах это есть, но я хотел узнать, что прописано в `Manifest.xml` и в `Activity` и в `Layout`? Как все-таки по нажатию на видео всплывает окно с выбором смотреть или скачать? Нигде ничего не могу найти по андроид.

Comment: Т.е. вы для Eclipse нашли, а для AS нет?.. Так не бывает. Ваш вопрос никак не может быть связан со средой разработки. А по сути... Ну, чтобы что-то проиграть - нужна ссылка. Видать просто HTML на лету правится и добавляется отлов нажтий на эти ссылки с запуском интента на скачивание.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а откуда вообще eclipse взялся? o_O

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну... Я только его ещё как IDE для Android на java знаю)

Comment: это же плагины делают, а не браузер

Comment: Вместо браузера, вы наверно хотите что-то вроде [YouTubeDL](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) программы/библиотеки на Питоне, которая умеет скачивать видео со многих сайтов и есть установленный механизм по добавлению новых (не пиратских) сайтов. Среди кучи приложений, которые заявляли способность скачивания видео с различных потоковых видео-сайтов, youtube-dl достаточно надёжным и быстро-обновляемым оказался. На iOS, эта библиотека к примеру из под Pythonista 3 работает. На Android, в рамках Kivy можно попробовать запустить или другой способ запустить python (или готовое приложение поискать).

Answer (score 1):

Если ставить цель по создантю новых браузеров, я бы рекомендовал обратить внимание на "движки" для браузеров, к примеру `Webkit` вот [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) по нему. Вот сайт [webkit](https://webkit.org/). На нем работает хром и сафари. Что касается по скачке файлов (видео и других) с сайтов, то это уже всё ручками кодить придется. Да кстати вот нагуглил [список всех движков для создания браузеров](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA). Большинство браузерных движков написаны на C++.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio - среда разработки приложений для ОС Android. Решение вам нужно искать, применительно к платформе (Android), а не инструменту (условно - сложному текстовому редактору Android Studio), а написать код найденного решения вы можете и в блокноте, с тем же самым успехом. Это на будущее.

Обработка контента веб-страницы осуществляется браузером, а не операционной системой. Соответственно вам нужно работать с HTML кодом, скриптами, API испльзуемого web-плеера и пр. - средствами браузера, а не с манифестами, разметками и активити, которые являются средствами системы.

Перехват закачек на стрим-видео обычно осуществляют через разработку **плагина (расширения) для движка браузера**, который и реализует и получение самой ссылки и диалоги скачать и прочий интерфейс.  Разработка такого плагина не имеет ничего общего с ОС, на которой запущен браузер, а зависит только от выбранного в браузере движка и вопросы по его изготовлению нужно задавать в соответствующих местах.

Более того, для стриминга видео могут использоваться разные плееры, в том числе собственные, с защитой от перехвата ссылки на закачку, поэтому одного универсального решения для всех сайтов не существует.